# Is it a fallacy to argue that if something is much much more likely to occur then it is in fact the case?

Tags: paradox, probability, reason

### Is it OK to argue that what is hugely more likely to occur is in fact the case?

There seems to be a class of paradox that relies on the idea that what we think is the case is in fact much much less likely to occur by chance than some other scenario, usually highly counter-intuitive, the suggestion being that we should reject the former is *in fact* the case. e.g. [Boltzmann brains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain):

> The paradox states that if one considers the probability of our
>   current situation as self-aware entities embedded in an organized
>   environment versus the probability of stand-alone self-aware entities
>   existing in a featureless thermodynamic "soup", then the latter should
>   be vastly more probable than the former.

Another example may be the idea, and I'm sorry but I forgot who to cite, that we're not alive for so much of the existence of the universe, reality, that *it makes no sense*, and the odds are we alive for more of it than we think.

Or perhaps the idea that the universe or multiverse is so huge that *the odds are* that our minds will repeat or re-occur someplace else.

Is this a class of paradox?

Comment: It is better now. I assume we are talking about heuristic reasoning here, not mathematics. Then it is reasonable to downrate scenarios that require unlikely events if an alternative is at all possible, think of catastrophes and saltations once used to "explain" evolution. This does not mean that they did not happen at all (in rare cases we know they did), but "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence" rule applies. Paradox and fallacy are two different things. When something factual "seems" unlikely we have a paradox, the argument for why it is unlikely, or likely, may be a fallacy.

Comment: @Conifold that's quite helpful actually, think I do make that mistake. I guess there's no fallacy general to all paradoxes of this type, else they would not be called paradoxes hah

Comment: @Conifold are these bad explanations of evolution (not sure what you refer to?) unlikely in the same way as the Boltzmann claim that we are not really brains? something that is a fluke (that i am not a Boltzmann brain) need not have little evidence for it. right? also is the following wrong? A has 1/3 chance. If A then B. So B has at least a 1/3 chance.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what "in the same way" or "something that is a fluke need not have little evidence for it" mean. [Saltations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saltation_(biology)) are certainly less likely than regular mutations since multiple genes have to be altered at once. The probability claim is technically right under ironclad inference, but such ironcladness rarely applies in empirical contexts, for heuristic inference it might be less due to the uncertainty of the inferring.

Comment: @Conifold this is obviously not a helpful discussion in this format, as i'm clearly failing to communicate. i just mean that what really was unlikely (smith winning the lottery) can happen.

Comment: @Conifold suppose that williams really has a 1/3 success rate at a guessing game. He guesses A, and if he's right then A. Is the chance of A at least 1/3? No, because Steve has a 7/8 success rate, and guessed not A.

Comment: That unlikely can happen is certainly true, but what you are asking has something to do with applying this in the context of scientific reasoning (I think). In that context guessing game analogies and other probabilistic toy examples are likely to lead to misleading conclusions because the reasoning is only plausible. For example, "williams has a 1/3 success rate" is just an inference from empirical frequency, hence "really" is always uncertain

Comment: @Conifold i don't follow. what if williams was a machine that will randomly tell us the right answer 1/3rd of the time. and steve likewise, but 7/8ths of the time. the probability that A if williams tells us A is not anything like 1/3rd if steve says not A

Comment: Let's go back to your question, what is it exactly at this point? If you are asking whether arguing that unlikely events do not happen is a fallacy the answer is yes, but few would commit it. If you are asking whether it is illegitimate to presume that unlikely events do not happen until proven otherwise, the answer is no. Is there more to it?

Comment: @Conifold well is that how the Boltzmann brain paradox is working? A is much more likely than B, so without any evidence against A then A

Comment: It would work this way if "A is much more likely than B" was uncontested. In the case of Boltzmann brains this conditional relies on a number of assumptions, including cosmological speculations about thermodynamic "soup" and questionable statistical counts, that do not obtain on some interpretations of quantum physics.